# How to get a victory medal on the Teutoburg Forest historical battle?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I've won on the Teutoburg Forest several times by getting my Eagle Cohorts out of the forest, but the game hasn't given me any victory medal for it.
I thought that maybe I should defeat all of the enemies instead of running away, despite both qualifying as a victory, but it's much more difficult to do so, and I'm not sure if it'd work either.
**Therefore, is there a proper way to get a medal on the Teutoburg Forest or is it just broken?**